# Google Analytics API count LandingPages meeting regex per year of month

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

Hi I'm looking to use the Google Analytics API in Google Spreadsheets to count the number of pages and sessions matching a regex statement.

Metrics:
`ga:sessions`

Dimensions:

`ga:yearMonth
ga:deviceCategory`

Filters:

`ga:LandingPagePath=~/tag/[0-9]{4,8}`

Comment: Is there any issue?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out the number of landing pages that meet the requirement, is there some sort of metric?

Comment: add dimension `ga:landingPagePath` in your query